# gl_FragCoord - insuffucient definition in ES Shading Language?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, gpu, opengl-es-3.0

It appears to me that `gl_FragCoord` is not sufficiently defined in the ES shading language specification: [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragCoord.xml)

What is missing in my opinion is a specification of where pixel centers are supposed to lie: at integer coordinates or right between them. In contrast the regular Shading Language Specification of `gl_FragCoord` has this nailed down: [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragCoord.xml)

Worse even I get mixed results on different platforms: An ARM Mali T604 seems to follow the .5 convention whereas an Adreno 330 seems to put the pixel centers at full integers (both tested on Android 4.4.2).

Can someone enlighten me on what's best practice here?

Comment: You can always add a sub-pixel shift (to pre-transformed coordinates) of 0.375,0.375 as a compromise. This has long been a trick used to get  the pixel centers for triangles, points and raster position (not in GLES) to line-up consistently (as they all have different rules for rasterization coverage). It should result in rounding the coordinates to the correct location if for some reason the rules differ. Generally the convention is top-left for polygons and center for points.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the actual [specification document](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.4.pdf), I found this:

```
1.1.4 Changes from OpenGL GLSL 3.3:

Removed:
 * Layout qualifiers: index, origin_upper_left and pixel_center_integer
```

I don't know these qualifiers were omitted from OpenGL ES, and I couldn't find a clear mention which convention is the correct one (or if it's left for implementations to decide), although I think the traditional way is at half-integer coordinates. In any case, looks like you'll have to add some code to e.g. round the values down to get consistent behaviour.

By the way, the man pages are not to be trusted - they tend to omit a lot of stuff and contain errors. Specification is always the authority.